# Why did I receive a question quality warning?

Tags: discussion, support, quality-filter

I asked a [C++ question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256140/how-to-do-vector-ops-on-a-vector-string-item-c) and it vectored off into a discussion about the sort, so left it for a while, not sure how to make it better.  Later came back with different example -- was told new example was easy (no example given that answered the question), and asked what my problem was -- was even shown how to get another non-answer of addressing the outermost data struct.

I went off to try to test and came back on a browser history page to a question page where I was told I was in danger of being blocked for bad questions. The message I got was:

> **Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.**
>
> **For help
>   formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good
>   question?**
>
> **Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and
>   clarity.**

I had a 2nd Q with 0 score and no downvotes at the time, but YIKES!... WTBB!!!  All of a sudden I felt bad and wrong and had no clue what I'd done other than be "unstellar and/or unpopular in asking questions that were hard to answer. I've barely gotten started on this site and already received warnings for not being good enough.

Looking at my stats I see 4 total questions. 2 had a +1 on the question and a total of +13 rep.  Two had a 0 rating on the Q. So where are the heavily down voted/zero voted/deleted posts? One or two "bad" posts (posts that are not easily answered by the normal site readers?).

Now, of note, I had just done a first revision on this question because people were answering part of the question that I hadn't meant for there to be focus on.  But that rewrite also resulted in a -1 on the Q, and a claim that it worked fine, so I tried to make that work and was accused of going off into the weeds.

If I so easily trigger warnings on questions that weren't horrible - and even after 2 rewrites, I think people are even less clear about what I was asking - then I was hoping that the same level of "AI" put into the warning system, could be put into the a system that is a bit more specific on what was being done wrong and how to fix it.

I thought a bit more hand-holding might be helpful for people making such novice errors.

Comment: Please link to your question so we can gather more information as to why it was closed/downvoted.

Comment: Was it this question - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/256140/how-to-do-vector-ops-on-a-vector-string-item-c ? If so, it was migrated to Stack Overflow.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Should we be afraid to ask questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255517/839601) at MSO (FWIW you hardly qualify as "beginner" - 6 months at Programmers, over 2 years at Stack Overflow)

Comment: is your issue similar to one described in [“You have asked terrible questions, please get away or ask better question”](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6726/31260) - where asker was "guilty" of _infrequently_ asking not very well received questions?

Comment: @whatsisname - as reference only -- not to get into a discussion about that Q(please); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845941/how-to-do-vector-ops-on-a-vector-string-item-c; What I got was an "automated message"... will edit Q w/more details.

Comment: @gnat -- in evaluating 'beginner', you need to look at number of contributions and questions asked.  I registered, ages ago to ask or answer some question -- I have answered more than asked, but in searching for my own stuff , If I see something I might be able to answer I try to add something.  That is VERY far from making me "experienced" on the site.  See the difference?

Comment: @gnat -- in regards to your 2nd Q, I'd say it was very similar --- and Paul's comment strikes a chord in how I am feeling about this as well:

> Which I still find silly. I have no idea why I am 
> "hitting a block".. This (apparently new?) system 
> gives no feedback and i really have no idea what I can 
> do to fix this.

Comment: Also, I don't see why this Q about "SE" issues, was tossed back into meta.prog.se?   How is this only about programmersSE, or is the prog.SE site the only one that puts up question bans for having 2 questions with 0 votes?...

Comment: this was migrated to Progremmers.SE because you've got warning about questions quality at this site; that is users and moderators here are assumed to be best qualified to evaluate whether it was fair or not

Comment: I was trying to focus on process rather than specifics which was why I was vague about the question to begin with.  If this becomes another 'focus on specifics of this persons case', then one can always come up with reasons to support specific cases, rather than looking at the problem on a more systemic basis.  Perhaps the tendency to steer away from beneficial solutions that are cross site applicable and view each case in isolation is part of the problem?  I.e. forcing each question about such into a separate 'case' vs. a class-action?

Comment: consider clarifying whether you're interested in [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268147/839601) or [Is it OK to downvote new users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268142/839601), or whether it should be that [first question doesn't count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/165773) when system decides on warning / rate limiting, or whether you are interested to learn what went wrong with [your removed posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/165773) (FWIW your posts that aren't removed shouldn't trigger a warning)

Comment: I tried to focus your question to the actual issue, and in doing so I removed quite a large part of it. If you feel my edit is too drastic, or that it changes the intent of the question, please feel free to roll back.

Comment: @YannisRizos since you chimed in anyway, consider providing details on deleted questions - inquiring minds want to know if the warning was triggered by some ancient faux-pas, like it was in [prior similar question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6729/31260)

Comment: @gnat One auto-deleted migration stub. The warning does seem a bit too eager here, although there might be something I'm missing.

Comment: @YannisRizos one? only one??? if this is indeed so then is sorta totally trashes the idea that [first question doesn't count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/165773) for question warning / block. Or, given that it probably wasn't first question, proves that correct approach would be that [first **bad** question doesn't count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237351/165773). Don't get me wrong I like it when system limits bad askers but cases like this simply jeopardize it

Comment: @gnat The only thing that stands out (a bit) is that the two migrations (the deleted one and the one that triggered the warning) were posted in a row (although almost a month apart). Perhaps the system didn't quite like that the OP's last couple of questions were deemed off topic, without at least one "good" question in between. /speculation

Comment: @YannisRizos thanks! so it's two not one, and all visible to asker (earlier than 60 days), right? That way it's not as ugly as I thought, but still, as you described it, somewhat too eager. Both questions ([1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/252908/how-to-declare-a-const-pointer-that-can-be-used-as-this?noredirect=true), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/256140/how-to-do-vector-ops-on-a-vector-string-item-c?noredirect=true)) are 0/0 votes, fairly neutral. Only thing is both have answers, Shog once mentioned that algorithm dislikes deletion of answered questions

Comment: But they were not really "deleted", but "migrated"... which I haven't normally seen as "bad", (if someone else knows better than me where the question would be better answered, more power to them!)... but now, I should view any migrated questions as a personal attack?  I don't think that makes sense -- especially not for automated bean-counter messages.

Comment: @YannisRizos -- edit fine... I tend to give too much detail BECAUSE I don't want to be accused of leaving out some detail that someone else thought important, but that I would have glossed over -- so I try to be as true to the situation as possible, which is NOT what is helpful for the "TLDR" crowd.  Unfortunately, between leaving out details that "SOME" have (in the past) said were important, and not wanting to appear to bias the topic, I've erred on the side of verbosity.  (Sorry)  not sure how best to change that, but your edit was fine and worked for me and original is still accessible.

Comment: gnat-- FWIW -- I really don't think migrated Q's should be triggering warnings...  not knowing the best place for a Q out of 50+ (or 100 counting overflow?), seems like something a computer program should be working to classify and figure out.  I sure as heck wouldn't have a clue if other groups would be more appropriate or why something even gets moved from prog -> overflow.  That's WAY unclear.

Comment: I just noticed something in the migration .. where it said the Q was moved from the prog.SE site -- a site for programmers interested in "Conceptual questions about programming"... i.e. META QUESTIONS!?!...  you wanna talk confusing?... I thought programming for for Q's about programming problems and meta was more for the conceptual as well as site Q's.... Having the main site be a "Meta" site (Q's About Programming in general vs. Q's about Programming Problems) is more than a little unclear for anyone in SW who understands what Meta means -- ???  How can this not be confusing to people?

Comment: as a site regular, I believe that it's generally fair that migrated questions could trigger warning. I am here to learn and share on-topic knowledge, not to read off-topic questions and redirect those who don't know. Think is though, in your particular case, warning doesn't look okay, the harm done by two zero-voted, successfully migrated questions in a month isn't much per se, and coupled with the fact that your other questions were received fine, it feels plain wrong

Comment: @gnat -- well that's why I posted to meta-SE, and not meta.programmers exchange, since it seems the system code is broken -- not that there was some 'judgment' needed about the questioned that spawned this topic.

Do you, perhaps, now understand why I'm beginning to think there might be some systemic flaw that are more appropriate to be discussed on the main site rather than migrated off to a side site?  Or is there something different about prog.se that makes its algorithms different from the other sites?

Comment: systemic flaws questions are okay at any meta, SE developers watch over these everywhere. As for your question prior to edit, it looked like in a need of site-specific quality evaluation

Comment: shoot first, clarify later? P.S. I still have no idea why the other Q was migrated either, it was a programming Q, that was xfered to a meta site about programming -- that remains unanswered with posted code.  (even was told my code would work if I changed valarrays to vectors... not even ... so I haven't had practice writing Q's on this site and it has very specific requirements.  That gets back to making the site less intimidating to newbies/novices.  For someone with as little experience on site as me, I feel raked over the coals.

Comment: @Astara Stack Overflow == Implementation & programming tools questions. Programmers == Conceptual questions (workflow, practices, theory, etc). Meta == Questions about the community, the site and the engine that drives it. All this is documented in our help center.

Comment: @gnat -- don't know if this belong in a new Q, but I am having trouble posting an update the Q that was migrated from prog to stackoverflow -- it just complains 'vaguely' about code formatting probs...even though it worked before and the preview looks fine... but now I can't update that Q with why it was confusing to people (it's a compiler bug and they are using different tools that don't have it).

Comment: asked for clarification at MSE: [For quality blocks / warnings, system seems to penalize migrated answered questions the same as deleted ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240660/165773)

Comment: thanks.... that seems unfortunate, IMO... but I know better than to argue with a cabal making secret rules.